# `onblur` on `input` is triggered when user clicks on link, how to prevent it?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with `input` component.
I want to check if user typed proper email so I use `onblur` event to check if.
I also have an `a` html element, when user clicks it, it should skip the whole form checking and open another url.

Problem is: the `onblur` of the `input` is triggered, which is not intended.

How can I NOT handle `onblur` of the input when user click on the `a` element?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your code. Without a code sample, it's difficult to explain.

Comment: Artom Pozdnyakov got the question right

Answer (score 0):

For example, something crude like this:

```
<input id="input">
<a href="#" id="dontMindMe">Link</a>
```

```
document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener(click, event => {
    if (event.target.id !== "dontMindMe" {
        doStuff();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it, you want to process onBlur everytime, except when clicked on link?

There will always be onBlur before click on link, but you can wrap your logic with

```
const onBlur = () => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { ...doStuff... });
}
```

Then in link's onClick clearTimeout(timeoutId). You would probably save timeoutId in useRef.

Comment: Yes, I want to process onBlur everytime except when user clicks on the link.
Do I do something really weird that I need such an extraordinary solution with `timeOuts`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done:

```
onMouseDown={(event) => onMouseDown(event)} <- in `a` component    

const onMouseDown = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

What it does (at least this is what I think it does):

- `onMouseDown` comes before `onBlur` on given `input`
- `event.preventDefault()` stops propagating the `event` thus `onBlur` is not triggered